# Command output location

Tags: linux, bash, shell, authentication, command

I am trying to find out where is the output of following command directed:

sudo -i -u someuser /home/someuser/test.sh

Content of test.sh script:

```
echo "test"
```

Command is invoked from home directory of another user.

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo - check the -i option. have you tried running the command as the someuser? is the environment set up in a weird way?

Comment: `echo` simply prints to standard output, and nothing here indicates that it is being redirected. Unless you are omitting crucial information, output will be to the invoking user's terminal.

Comment: Command behaves as expected when run as someuser. I have checked that command on my local PC and it is ok. However on remote server it is different. I've noticed that command: sudo -i -u someuser /home/someuser/test.sh prints nothing. However command sudo -i -u someuser ./test.sh prints expected text 'test'.

Comment: I guess it is permission problem. Is it possible that permissions of all parent directories are checked?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to find out this is to run pwd(1) with sudo, though I'll spoil the fun and reveal that when sudo(1) is executed with '-i' switch the working directory will be set to effective user id (= whatever is specified with '-u' or root when left unspecified) and without '-i' it'll be the current directory.

Example:

```
user@host:~/work/linux-3.11.7$ sudo -i -u games pwd
[sudo] password for user: 
/usr/games
user@host:~/work/linux-3.11.7$ sudo -u games pwd
/home/user/work/linux-3.11.7
```

So in case you'll redirect output of sudo(1) to some file without a full path specified, that's how you know where the file will be created.